# How to change upload file type with random name before upload and insert in DB using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter for upload file , how to change file name with random name before uploading and insert to DB 
this is a part of function

```
$cv=$_FILES['cv']['name'];
            $config = array('upload_path' => './assets/uploads/','allowed_types' => 'pdf|doc',);  
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Comment: $config['encrypt_name'=>true]  the file name will be converted to a random encrypted string

Comment: :) how to insert encrypt_name to DB :?